# How can I compile this older Fortran code?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I'm attempting to compile Fortran code that was written and compiled in the late eighties on a `DEC` operating system. I'm not sure what version of Fortran the code is written in.

I'm on `macOS` version `10.14.6`, and using `gfortran` version `8.2.0`.

When I attempt to compile on the command-line with:

`gfortran -v -fdec- o test CODE.FOR`

I receive the following error:

```
CODE.FOR:1618:72:

CODE.FOR: 1599:72:

CODE.FOR:1618.72:

Error: Variable 'j' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
```

When I look at the line 1618, I see: `J=J-1`, which is inside a `DO` loop.

Is the code so old that this used to compile on an older compiler but now on `gfortran` it won't allow variable `j` to be changed in a `DO` loop?

```
      DO 10 J=1,NMAX
      WRITE(6,*)' Give STA NAME, COMP(Z, R, or T), and WAVE TYPE (P, SV,
     * or SH)'
      WRITE(6,*)' Enter blanks to quit'
      WRITE(6,*)' Reenter STA NAME, COMP and WAVE TYPE to replace old or
     *incorrect data'
      WRITE(6,*)' Separate each entry by a space (STA NAME is 4 chars)'
      READ(5,2) SN(J),COMP(J),PS(J)
2     FORMAT(A,1X,A,1X,A)
      IF (SN(J).EQ.'    ') GO TO 900
      WRITE(6,*)' Give DIST, AZ, and AMP'
      READ(5,*) R(J),AZ(J),AMP(J)
      IF (J.GT.1) THEN
        DO 11 I=1,J-1
        IF (SN(J).EQ.SN(I).AND.COMP(J).EQ.COMP(I).AND.PS(J).EQ.PS(I))
     *   THEN
            R(I)=R(J)
            AZ(I)=AZ(J)
            AMP(I)=AMP(J)
            J=J-1
            GO TO 10
        END IF
11      CONTINUE
      END IF
10    CONTINUE
```

Comment: We really need to see that code. However, you must likely have to correct the code to be standard conforming. Your code is not valid Fortran and it wasn't valid Fortran in the 80s either.

Comment: But if it is doing what you are saying the code is broken - this has never been allowed in standard Fortran. You will have to find a compiler than offers it as an extension - I don't know of one.

Comment: @VladimirF What's the best way for me to share the code?

Comment: The code on this site should always be copy-pasted in the question itself. Just make a relevant example.  The loop is probably enough and the inside can be simplified.

Comment: What you show is not enough. The code you show is perfectly compilable by gfortran.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your help, there is a 30k character limit and the code is 90k chars. I just edited with the subroutine that has the `J=J-1` error in it. If that's not enough, can I send you a text file with the code somehow?

Comment: This is fine, the relevant loop is `DO 10 J=1,NMAX`.

Comment: Apparently the DEC compiler around the time of the transition from F66 to F77 allowed this with a warning. From https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-18.html    "   There are compilers (e.g. DEC FORTRAN), that some of the time do 
   use the control-variable to test for termination, in this case
   changing its value may cause wrong results (DEC FORTRAN issues a 
   warning when doing so). Anyway, this is a bad programming practice."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing the iteration variable J of loop

```
DO 10 J=1,NMAX
```

in

```
J=J-1
```

That is not allowed.

You can easily rewrite any indexed DO loop to a non-indexed do loop.

```
     DO 10 J=1,NMAX

         if (..) J = J - 1
     10 CONTINUE
```

becomes

```
     J = 1
     DO

         if (..) J = J - 1

         J = J + 1

         if (J > NMAX) exit
     END DO
```

or

```
     J = 1
     DO WHILE (J<=NMAX)

         if (..) J = J - 1

         J = J + 1

     END DO
```